# how to get input from html using python socket

Tags: python, html, sockets, localhost

I have a code to start a simple socket sever on localhost. However, I want it to display a html page when it is accessed through browser. The html will contain two text fields and submit button. When user enters text in text fields and clicks on submit button, I want the program to read from text fields. How Can I Do That?

Comment: you can start simple HTTPServer/ baseHTTPServer  using python

Comment: Yes, I Know But I am Want it to be a Socket Server. It's A requirement of my project

Comment: why wont look source code of BaseHTTPServer.py  ? its using socket module

Comment: I am Afraid with my current knowledge of socket i will not be able to understand it

Comment: @TalhaAhmad Look at it anyway! It won't hurt.

Comment: See [WSGIServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wsgiref.html#wsgiref.simple_server.WSGIServer).

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69763356/how-to-get-form-value-using-python-sockets

Answer (score 5):

*The instant answer (I hope so) to your question is in the last section* **The Answer** - *and, if I have interpreted your question wrong, let me know in the comment section*.

---

**The confusion** - You are confusing the fundamentals - to display a html page, you simply need a server (localhost in your case), and the browser will use the `HTTP`/`HTTPS` protocol to fetch that content/response/html page. In Python (almost same for other languages) there are two levels of access to network services:

- Low-level via `sockets`.
- Higher-level via application level network protocols, like `HTTP`, `FTP`, etc.

**Sockets** - in plain english it is a functionality (interface) provided by the machine's operating system to implement client and server (for the higher-level network protocols) like communication between the processes. These processes can be running on a same machine or both processes on physically apart machines (e.g. requesting a website using browser).

A typical socket client is (asking for the desired html from browser):

```
client_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_sock.connect(("localhost", 80))
```

But to make it work you must already have server running (which will serve the html):

```
server_sock = socket.socket()     # Create a socket object
server_sock.bind((localhost, 80)) # Bind to the port
server_sock.listen(5) 
while True:
     # lines for whatever we want server to do
```

The line `server_sock.bind((localhost, 80))` has binded (assigned/allocated) the localhost:80 (a socket is basically 'host_name:port_number') to this `server_sock` i.e. any call/request to `localhost:80` will be handled as per the lines in the above `while True:` block of the code above, can be a text response, HTML, etc.

---

**Typical web scenario** - We enter a website name *www.google.com* (which is resolved into an IP via `DNS` protocol - a whole another story) and hit enter, we'll get the Google's search homepage in response - Here you're the client, that is entering the website name and hitting enter is technically `client_sock.connect('www.google.com', 80)`, and it only worked because on another (remote) machine/system/host they have `server_socket` binded and listening i.e.

```
server_sock.bind('machine's_IP', 80)
server_sock.listen(5)
while True:
    #accept connections from outside
    (client_socket, address) = server_socket.accept()

    # here will be the lines which send us back the Google's 
    # homepage html as a response to our web request.
```

---

To sum-up, servers (webserver in your case) can be implemented using (almost) any programming languages e.g. python or C, etc, but the basis, the lowest layer, exactly where the data is passed between 2 processes whether on the same machine using `locahost` (loopback) or each process running on physically apart machine/host (typical web scenario ) via the `HTTP` (`TCP`) protocol rest upon sockets. **Sockets are the fundamental building block** from which `HTTP`, `HTTPS`, `FTP`, `SMTP` protocols (all of these are TCP-type protocols) are defined.

`DNS`, `DHCP`, `VOIP` protocols are `UDP` protocols but they too are built on top of sockets.

---

**The Answer** - To start, create a web_server.py and paste the following code (only to see how it works) and run the file as script i.e. from the file's location run "python

web_server.py" in command prompt/terminal:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket

host = 'localhost'
port = 80
server_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,\
                            socket.SOCK_STREAM)    # Create a socket object
server_sock.bind((host , port))                    # Bind to the port

print 'Starting server on', host, port
print 'The Web server URL for this would be http://%s:%d/' % (host, port)

server_sock.listen(5)             # Now wait for client connection.

print 'Entering infinite loop; hit CTRL-C to exit'
while True:
    # Establish connection with client.    
    client_sock, (client_host, client_port) = socket.socket.accept()
    print 'Got connection from', client_host, client_port
    client_sock.recv(1000) # should receive request from client. (GET ....)
    client_sock.send('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n')
    client_sock.send('Content-Type: text/html\n')
    client_sock.send('\n') # header and body should be separated by additional newline
    # you can paste your 2 text field html here in the <body>
    client_sock.send("""
        <html>
        <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1> this is my server!
        </body>
        </html>
    """) 
    client_sock.close()
```

---

**P.S.** You have to implement a HTTP server (webserver) - which will definitely use the socket interface at the lowest level i.e.

```
server_sock.bind
server_sock.listen
server_sock.accept
```

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful and i have  send a html form to browser but how to get input from the form

Comment: i want the form to pass python the data of the form after user press submit button

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you can achieve it the usual way i.e. use the 'action' attribute in the <form> tag. The value of the 'action=formprocessor.py' can be a python script for processing the form data - place the formprocessor.py in the same directory where the server script/file is.